# Использовать ли ООП в маленьком учебном проекте или нет?

Tags: python, sql, ооп, tkinter, структуры

Уважаемые опытные знатоки, очень нужно ваше разъяснение по следующему тревожащему меня вопросу, как начинающего программиста.
Начал писать свою программку на tkinter, подключил к ней базу данных на Sql - получилась такая простая графическая программа с кнопками и хранилищем списка книг для пользователя и обновляемой им базой данных.
У меня где-то около 300 строк кода в ней. И вот вопрос, я не использовал ООП. Читал и слышал, что ООП нужно для больших проектов, там, где программа растёт и для её удобства следует оформлять код через ООП, а без необходимости не прикручивать его везде, куда только можно, что нужно соблюдать вроде как логичность использования. Хотя в интернете встречал подобные моему проекты с большим количеством строк допустим 400-500 и там было ООП, хотя они не намного сложнее моего кода.
В связи с этим встал вопрос, подскажите когда нужно оформлять код через использование ООП, а когда это лишнее. Я хочу понять, может я что-то не так делаю и посмотрят на мой проект скажут: а чего это ты не использовал ООП или наоборот посмотрят и скажут: ну и на кой черт тут эти классы?
Если конкретно: насколько большой должен быть проект для ООП? Сколько строк там. Или когда в принципе мне заморачиваться, а когда просто кодить и не думать о таком?

Comment: На питоне в принципе нельзя писать без ООП, так как в питоне все является объектом.

Comment: Terry, вы должны использовать парадигму, которая лучше всего соответствует задаче 
и, следовательно, создает более простой и читаемый код, 
а значит, его легче отлаживать и поддерживать.

Comment: Напишите две версии: с ООП и без неё. Выберите, какая больше понравится.

Comment: Ну например, у вас уже используется SQL (неназванный). Допустим, вы захотите использовать другой SQL движок (например, MySQL вместо SQLite или что у вас там) - вам придется прям в основном коде править. Или вы захотите использовать какую-то облачную no-sql базу, а у вас прямо в коде SQL запросы прописаны. Вот абстрагирование от конкретной реализации хранения через ООП и паттерн Репозиторий помогло бы упростить доработку кода. Но прикручивать ООП везде, и весь код оборачивать в класс конечно не нужно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ооп - это методология программирования. Так же как, например, и функциональное программирование - это всего навсего методология.

От размера проекта не зависит, писать на ООП или Без него. По большому счёту, в чистой виде Ооп ни кто не применяет. Ооп больше используют как некие контейнеры структур. Но если у тебя все спроектированно хорошо, то и функциональный код с модулями будет работать замечательно.

То есть писать тебя свои личные проекты в той или иной методологии ни кто ни принуждает. И нет лучшего или худшего. Но прийдя в какой то проект, где используются те или иные фримворки и правила написания кода. Ты будешь уже писать в методологии, которой придерживается команда.

Comment: Спасибо, очень приятно читать такой основательный ответ на вопрос. Просто когда ищешь ответы на вопросы и встречаешь у таких же новичков маленькие проекты не сложнее твоего, которые изобилуют ООП - классы, селфы, то закрадывается мысль, что может я пишу код - некорректно, хотя я не вижу надобность в ООП например на данный момент

Comment: @Terry , не расслабляйтесь, основательно изучайте ООП.

Comment: @S.Nick спасибо, как раз сейчас начал в нём разбираться, чтобы он был в проектах, но всё же - скажите насколько он часто используется, есть ли крупные (относительно) проекты без ООП?

Comment: @Terry Без ОПП сложно себе представить какой-либо современный более-менее серьезный проект. Иногда можно встретить очень старый код написанный в процедурном стиле, его не возможно поддерживать и тем более добавлять новую функциональность, проще написать заново. Так что изучайте ООП и не тешьте себя надеждой на то, что можно обойтись без него :)

Comment: Поляков Роман
Не соглашусь, возьми react на js .Команда фэйсбука добавила к имеющимся классовым компаньонам компоненты функциональные. И можно весь проект написать на react не используя не одного класса. Очень много зависит от того на каком языке пишут. На асемблере например )) нет ни каких классов. И ничего пишут люди проги для железяк. Хорошая программа не зависит от методологии а зависит от инженера который ее изначально проектировал и внес ли он в изначальный проект возможности расширения. Грамотное проектирование вот ключ. И этому сегодня мало учат в университетах.